# Obj-C, request doesn't sent

Tags: objective-c

when I send a request to the the server with string in hebrew the request doesn't sent to the server, if I change the string to english it is work.

this is the code:

```
    NSString *feedtextMsg = @"היי";

URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@messagePage.php?swAction=takeFeedback&se=%@&fid=%@&autx=%@&msg=%@",sUrl,userID,anonymousUID,autx,feedtextMsg];
[self scaleFeedImage:feedBackPhoto];
NSData *storeData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(feedBackPhoto, 90);

NSMutableURLRequest *request  = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes: [URLString UTF8String] length: [URLString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", @"the"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:storeData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
sendreq = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
response =[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[sendreq bytes] length:[sendreq length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"res1: %@", response);
```

so if I change the string

```
NSString *feedtextMsg = @"היי";
```

to this

```
NSString *feedtextMsg = @"HI";
```

I get response from my PHP file.

in my PHP file the code is

```
die("res: ".$_Get["msg"]);
```

what should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:), `+[NSURL URLWithString:]` requires the URL string to conform to RFC 2396, which excludes Unicode characters. You could send the text in your form data or use percent aka. URL encoding.